# WordPress: rewrite rule with wildcard categories

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I've been browsing through the [Rewrite_API for WordPress and add_rewrite_rule documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule), trying to find a way to rewrite a type of URL's that a have on a football team's website.

The URL should look like this:

`domain.com/match/[season]/[title-of-post]/?type=something`

and I want this to redirect to:

`domain.com/match/[season]/[title-of-post]/something/`

Example: domain.com/match/premier-league-2018/chelsea-everton/something/

I thought this would be possible through something like this, but I soon realized that the `(.*?)` are parsed as match queries:

```
function match_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule( '^match/(.*?)/(.*?)/?$', 'index.php?type=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
add_action('init', 'match_rewrite', 10, 0);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex for something like this :

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rule( '^match/([a-z0-9-]+)/(([a-z0-9-]+)/?)*$', 'index.php?type=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

and tell me if it solve your issue

Comment: That just redirects me to the front page ("match" is a CPT, btw).